# Install OpenBSD from a USB flashdrive : "No OS" message on boot

Tags: usb, boot, installation, usb-flash-drive, openbsd

I'm attempting to install OpenBSD on a fancy new home server equipment I just bought.

I followed [this guide](http://devguide.net/openbsd/articles/creating-a-bootable-openbsd-usb-installation-drive) to create a bootable USB flash drive from an OpenBSD VM I have on my laptop.  But when I try to boot my laptop on it all I get is a "No OS" message.  I tried two different USB keys.

Does anyone know that problem and its solution?

Edit : fdisk on sd0 in the VM :

```
#fdisk sd0
Disk: sd0   geometry: 122/255/63 [1974271 Sectors]
Offset: 0   Signature: 0xAA55
            Starting         Ending         LBA Info:
 #: id      C   H   S -      C   H   S [       start:        size ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0: 00      0   0   0 -      0   0   0 [           0:           0 ] unused      
 1: 00      0   0   0 -      0   0   0 [           0:           0 ] unused      
 2: 00      0   0   0 -      0   0   0 [           0:           0 ] unused      
*3: A6      0   1   1 -    121 254  63 [          63:     1959867 ] OpenBSD
```

Comment: what steps did you follow to make the USB drive's MBR bootable?  the "No OS" message may be the BIOS telling you it can't find a bootable MBR.  this means either you've failed to make the MBR bootable, or the BIOS isn't actually trying to boot from that USB drive.

Comment: What does `fdisk sd0` say in the OpenBSD VM (assuming your USB drive shows up as `sd0` in OpenBSD)?  Is the asterisk indicating the bootable flag showing up next to the right MBR partition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of following that guide, why not just plug the usb stick into your main computer, boot from a CD, and install OBSD on the USB stick as if it were a regular Hard Drive? That's what I did and now I have a wonderful "live" USB stick to play around with that I can also use for installing OBSD.

Here's the directions right on openbsd.org's web site.
http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq14.html#flashmemLive

To use it as an install guide, put bsd.rd under / on the drive. When you boot the drive, tell it to use bsd.rd. That'll start the install.

I put the other install files under /usr/local//

Once I've boot bsd.rd, I just point to that location to install OpenBSD.